# SSIS File System Task (Copy File Operation) OverWriteDestination functionality

Tags: ssis

I was unable to find any documentation on the SSIS File System Task component **OverWriteDestination** property functionality  for a Copy File Operation.

I understand what it is used for but how does it actually cause the component to behave when the OverWriteDestination is set to false?

If set to False, will the component simply skip the file and not try to copy it or will it copy it with a different name, perhaps a number appended to the end of the file name being copied (for example filename(1).text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have OverwriteDestination set to False and your destination file already exists, then you will get an error stating something along the lines of

[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The file 'XXXXXXX' already exists.".

That is the default behavior if you do not chnage anything else.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS FileSystem Task is very limited in terms of features. Many times I have to use C# code in Script Task to fulfill missing features. Here is [example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) which shows how to copy file with Overwite option (See last argument true means overwrite)

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName), true);
```

If you strictly prefer clean workflow using Drag and Drop approach then you may have to use 3rd party Task [like this one](https://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/ssis-file-system-task-advanced/).